# How do I work with gamepad fall back devices in Unity's Input System?

Tags: unity, input, controllers, gamepad

I was applying  gamepad controls to my game & I found that the fall back device for my gamepad is a joystick. As I understand it, this is standard behavior for the new input system.

I also [read this link about overriding HID fallback](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/HID.html#overriding-the-hid-fallback). This is what I was doing by creating a custom scheme for my MSI gamepad.

There are multiple gamepad that Unity will detect only as joysticks, but I need them to be detected as gamepads, in order to properly use both their left and right sticks and allow their binding. If the device is recognized as joystick, it won't react to any gamepad scheme binding.

I found out that (in mentioned link) I can match devices by product name, manufacturer, etc. There can be also differences in their buttons as I had to remap completely such as the PS4 struct mentioned in link.

My questions are:

- Does every single gamepad differ with their offset and bits for the buttons or are the differences just between PS and XBox compatible devices?
- How can I handle gamepads that can fallback to joystick? I don't suppose that I have to map every single one... especially since I can't purchase every single gamepad to make it work with my game.
- How can a developer handle the various gamepads/controllers that they aren't even be aware of?

Comment: Strange. As of the latest version, as far as I am aware, control schemes don't actually do anything but organisation. It will read all valid inputs at all times...

Comment: PerformInteractiveBinding() awaits the similar binding as is defined the default. Anyway, If the gamepad is recognized as joystick, I cant get the Rz/Z axis properly and in the same way as the left stick... Generic joystick in Input System does not even have these axis.